# Typescript generics : forbid keys of nullable properties as method parameters

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

How can a prevent a method to accept a parameter of type `keyof this` where the property is nullable ?

Here is an example :

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass {
  get<K extends keyof this>(key: K): this[K] {
    return this[key];
  }

  getOptional<K extends keyof this>(key: K, defaultValue: this[K]): this[K] {
    return this[key] || defaultValue;
  }
}

class MyClass extends MyAbstractClass {
  foo: string = "ok";
  bar: number = 4;
  baz: boolean = true;
  optional?: {} = {};
}

const instance = new MyClass();

const yepItsAString: string = instance.get("foo"); // Ok
const yepItsOpitional: {} = instance.get("optional"); // <!= this should not work
```

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-339xg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a helper type `DefinedKeys` that uses a mapped type to leave out the keys for which the value includes `undefined`:

```
type DefinedKeys<T> = keyof {
  [K in keyof T as undefined extends T[K] ? never : K]: K
}
```

Then you can rewrite `get` to take the intersection of `keyof this` and `DefinedKeys<this>` to disallow keys for optional properties (you still need `keyof this` for TypeScript to infer that `K` can index `this`):

```
  get<K extends keyof this & DefinedKeys<this>>(key: K): this[K] {
    return this[key];
  }
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhBmBLAdhAJgaQiAzgHgBUA+KAXigGtsB7eKAbwCgooBtDKFSmugqAQxxQArsjQIU6KBAAewCGKEF2AXSgB+KKgBuEAE5QAXFAwrjGRgF9GjfgCMcwPfwDGwKC4A2goQFkQAIIOTq7AAMLeOEJMLADmEMB4HLLyitwgtFDAABaIQgBksBKomNj4OXlERAAUVCDmAJTGFTiqDMwsUHoJwnrIWbmtdSoA3B3WHfHAAPJgwIjUyPyeSdJyCmhCdZktNXXmADRQ4vD8wp7AAGrLwhDNg6pNA3ltMZ3dwL39LazDUAA+-2OCDOF2unluYxY1gmXh8UH8EXhKQ2fkCwWcbiRUXaLHg1GoxkcehQsTIUAARNQKBSoVA7Pw9MZkMIALZ2fTkgAsdIZAC9jHYCZ4IPx+uQnJCOtQ5gslp51MZ6JZycqxrDFo5OMhHGKXNByKgAO4IkDYnDVBpjRguTXuEAQMAASWAOACAGUnKSiV7kGTyChdch9QA6KbVCn46gUq1QAD0cag0woNrtUAdztds0Q80WyyVKoDOuAeogYYSEZluflMZG8cTeAlg2O1AgQmQ1HcRuoehTQA)

Comment: On my project, tsc throw a TS-2345 error : Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'

Comment: You can enforce it to be non-optional in the same way as `get`, but doesn't it make more sense to enforce optionality rather than non-optionality for `getOptional`? (you could do this by adding `& UndefinedKeys<this>`). Or do you mean actual nullable types? (nullable is different from optional, but from the code I thought you meant the latter)

Comment: My previous comment was an answer was to the comment that was deleted. I don't see that TS-2345 error in the sandbox though.